# Java Command line arguments not read

Tags: java

I have a class that contains the following main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("args.length: " + args.length);
    if (args.length == 1) {
        // do something
   } else if (args.length == 2){
       // do something
   }
    ... Some code ...
}
```

The problem is that the arguments in command line are not read.

When I type `./program arg1 Arg 2 ....` I always get `args.length` equals to `0`. I tried to verify the length of arguments in other classes and I got the correct number

What could be the problem ?

Comment: ./program ? Where does this executable come from ?

Comment: You would normally start a Java program with `java foo.bar.Baz arg1 arg2 ...` - what is `./program`? (If it's a shell script you've written to start the application, that's probably where the problem is.)

Comment: are you are running the program you think you are running? java program run like this btw: `java -cp <...> your.MainClass arg1 arg2 ...`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `program` is a script, it should look like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
java foo.bar.YourClass "$@"
```

It should now work with arguments

Answer (score -1):

./program is a script. 
In fact, I forgot to add $* at the end of " java -cp <...> myclass ". So, it was normal not to take into account the command line arguments.
Thanks for all of you !

Comment: -1 - Use `"$@"` instead of `$*` if you want quoted arguments to be handled correctly by the wrapper script.